# Have text that clears when you click on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, textinput

I would like to know how to implement something like stack overflow when you post a question: "At least one tag such as (css html asp.net), max 5 tags.

How can I implement something like this for a text input in html, where it is partially faded, but when you type, it doesn't show up, and is not faded.

I don't mind how to do this, as long as it works.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest option is to use the `placeholder` attribute:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="At least one tag, such as 'html', 'asp.net', max five tags." />
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/BqPdB/).

If cross-compatibility is a requirement, then JavaScript is also an option:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

for (i=0; i<inputs.length; i++){
    if (inputs[i].hasAttribute('data-hint')){
        inputs[i].value = inputs[i].getAttribute('data-hint');
            inputs[i].style.color = '#999';

        inputs[i].onclick = function(){
            this.value = '';
        };
        inputs[i].onblur = function(){
            if (this.value == '' || this.value == this.getAttribute('data-hint')){
                this.value = this.getAttribute('data-hint');
                this.style.color = '#000';
            }
        };
    }
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/BqPdB/1/).

Or, with jQuery:

```
$('input:text').each(
    function(){
        $(this).val($(this).attr('data-hint'));
            $(this).css('color','#999');
    }).click(
    function(){
        $(this).val('');
            $(this).css('color','#000');
    }).blur(
    function(){
        if ($(this).val() == ''){
            $(this).val($(this).attr('data-hint'));
            $(this).css('color','#999');
        }
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/BqPdB/2/).

References:

- [Common Input Element Attributes (W3.org)](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-placeholder-attribute).

Vanilla JavaScript:

- [`document.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName).
- [`element.onblur`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onblur).
- [`element.onfocus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onfocus).
- [`element.hasAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.hasAttribute).
- [`element.getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getAttribute).
- [`element.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.style).

jQuery:

- [text-input (`:text`) selector](http://api.jquery.com/text-selector/).
- [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
- [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).
- [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/).
- [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

Comment: Two things to note here: 1) click event should actually be focus. 2) this doesn't take care of the form submit. You would have to clear default values server side or handle onsubmit event.

Answer (score 5):

```
<input type="text" name="booga" placeholder="This is default text" />
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Your text here" />
```

Requires up-to-date browser, but doesn't use any code of any kind.

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Default text goes here..."/>
```

As @Kolink's answer explains, doing this requires an up-to-date browser, but doesn't use code at all.